# Matplotlib - How is rc_context() used?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib documentation, at https://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html, the following "pseudo example" is provided, followed by a short "pseudo explanation":

```
with mpl.rc_context(fname='screen.rc'):
  plt.plot(x, a)
  with mpl.rc_context(fname='print.rc'):
    plt.plot(x, b)
  plt.plot(x, c)
```

*The 'a' vs 'x' and 'c' vs 'x' plots would have settings from 'screen.rc', while the 'b' vs 'x' plot would have settings from 'print.rc'.*

---

For me, this is an "equation with 5 unknowns": 'screen.rc', 'print.rc', 'a', 'b' and 'c'. More specifically: 1) what are the files 'screen.rc' 'print.rc' and where are they found or how are they created? and 2) what do the variables 'a', 'b' and 'c' represent and how are they set?

It seems that this "example" is quite famous, since I have found an exact copy of it, including the short description, in a dozen of different places. What is most interesting is that no one, not even the matplotlib staff itself, cared to explain how can this stuff be actually applied.

Is there someone who has concrete information about this example or can one give a **concrete** example of how is `rc_context()` used?

Answer (score 6):

The example you show comes from the documentation of the respective method. Such methods have little space to go into much detail, so please don't blame the people for actually providing such example in the unusual place of a method docstring.

A more detailed explanation of the rc file, the context and examples are found in the [Customizing tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) (the second tutorial in the tutorials page, little chance to miss it).

Sticking to the case from the question, the concrete case is you have a python file which contains this code, and in addition you have two text files, named `screen.rc` and `print.rc`.

The .py file:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
a = [1,2,4,4]
b = [1,1,2,4]
c = [2,3,3,1]


with mpl.rc_context(fname='screen.rc'):
  plt.plot(x, a)
  with mpl.rc_context(fname='print.rc'):
    plt.plot(x, b)
  plt.plot(x, c)

plt.show()
```

The `screen.rc` file:

```
lines.linewidth   : 1       ## line width in points
lines.linestyle   : -       ## linestyle
```

The `print.rc` file:

```
lines.linewidth   : 5       ## line width in points
lines.linestyle   : :       ## linestyle
```

Running the py file would produce something like this as output

[image]

The blue line is the one created from `plt.plot(x, a)`. It has a solid linestyle and is one point wide. Similar, the green line,  `plt.plot(x, c)`, because both are inside the `screen.rc` context, but not within the `print.rc`. The orange line is the one created from within the `print.rc` context. It hence has a linewith of 5 points and is dotted.

Comment: Great, @Ernes. Thank you. So, the .rc files are config files using matplotlib.rcParams[]!  And  'x', 'a', 'b', 'c' are all lists of same length with x with y values. (If they used 'y1', 'y2' and 'y3', it would be less confusing.). About blaming: the Matplotlib tutorial I mentioned, as all the tutorials by matplotlib.org are useful but they are very bad. They are actually references. One has to search other matplotlib reference for rexamples. And the example in question is more confusing than helping, except if someone is quite knowledgeable on matplotlib, which it seems you are.

Comment: Oh, I have to add this: If they couldn't provide a workable example in their "tutorial" page they should better not including any but adding **a link to an example**. E.g. a link to **https://matplotlib.org/examples/**, also written by /matplotlib.org. This should always be the case. See, it's rather a matter of thinking or caring, not lack of space or time.

Comment: Matplotlib as well as its documentation are open source and community maintained. This means anyone, also you, can improve it; which people are also constantly doing, and they are not payed for it. It is quite natural that this is done mostly by people having a little more experience, so they might miss a bit or two which is important for beginners. Feel free to [contribute](https://matplotlib.org/devel/contributing.html#other-ways-to-contribute) with a suggestion on how to improve this.

Comment: I understand. And I would be happy to be able to contribute as you suggest, but the question is **how can I do that** if I don't have the necessary knowledge of matplotlib, which is exactly why I commented on this thread in the first place!!  This is a vicious circle! :))

Comment: I suppose now that you have understood the issue you would be able to tell how the documentation should handle this instead from your point of view.